# How do I use a users input to open a text file and then load it into a 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, file

This is what I have in my text file.

```
6814,85,86,92,88
7234,76,81,84,78
6465,87,54,68,72
7899,92,90,88,86
9901,45,78,79,80
8234,77,87,84,98
7934,76,91,84,65
7284,56,81,87,98
7654,76,87,84,88
3534,86,81,84,73
```

And this is what I've coded.

```
void getName(float arr1[x][y])
{
  FILE* graFile;
  float arr2[x][y];
  char userIn[50];
  printf("Enter filename: ");
  scanf("%s", userIn);
  graFile = fopen(userIn, "r");
  int studentId, test1, test2, test3, test4;

  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
      fscanf(graFile, "%d%d%d%d%d%f", &studentId, &test1, &test2, &test3, &test4, &arr2[i][j]);
      arr2[0][0] = studentId;
      arr2[0][1] = test1;
      arr2[0][2] = test2;
      arr2[0][3] = test3;
      arr2[0][4] = test4;
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
      printf("%f", arr2[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  fclose(graFile);
  return;
}
```

I have to write a program that asks the user to input the name of a text file (which contains grades), then load it into a 2D array. Then I have to sort the grades and take the average of the grades. I'm starting with my first function, which is to get the user input for a text file name and load it into a 2D array. I'm still new to C programming and I'm having a hard time understanding 2D arrays. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Please provide your code in text form in your post

Comment: it is far, far easier for others to help when your source code and inputs and outputs are *in* the body of your question, as text, *not* as images;  I have to think it would have been fewer steps for you, as well, to paste what is already text into the text of your question;  also, please clarify exactly what *isn't* working

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of what you have tried and exactly why it is not doing what you want

Comment: are `x` and `y` global variables?  MUCH better to modify the function signature to: `void getarray( int x, int y, arry[][y] )`

Comment: regarding: `scanf( "%s", userin );`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using `%s` and/or `%[...]`  always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer to avoid any possibility of a buffer overflow and the associated undefined behavior.  Use 1 less than the actual length of the input buffer because those two format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input

Comment: when calling: `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, the call `perror( "fopen failed" );` so both your error message and the text reason the OS thinks the operation failed are written to `stdout`

Comment: Sorry, yes I have int x = 10; and int y = 6; in my main.

Comment: if the variables `x` and `y` are in `main()`, then they will NEVER be available to the posted function, unless passed as parameters

Comment: when calling `fscanf()` (or any one of that family of functions) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  For instance: if( fscanf(graFile, "%d%d%d%d%d%f", &studentId, &test1, &test2, &test3, &test4, &arr2[i][j] != 6 )  {  fprintf( stderr, "fscanf for reading a line from the input file failed\n" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: why read the values from the file into temporary variables?  Why not read them directly into the `arr2[]` fields?

Comment: regarding: `arr2[0][0] = studentId;
      arr2[0][1] = test1;
      arr2[0][2] = test2;
      arr2[0][3] = test3;
      arr2[0][4] = test4;`  This will always copy into the first record in the `arr2[]`  suggest: `arr2[i][0] = studentId;
      arr2[i][1] = test1;
      arr2[i][2] = test2;
      arr2[i][3] = test3;
      arr2[i][4] = test4;`  and when reading the data, this statement: `for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {` is not correct and should be removed

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly 'types' variables for the expected input
4. properly checks for errors
5. uses `puts()` when appropriate
6. properly outputs error messages to `stderr`
7. avoids unnecessary variable declarations and data copying
8. consistently indents the code
9. uses horizontal spacing, when appropriate, for readability
10. properly uses a format string in calls to `printf()`
11. separates code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case`, `default` via a single blank line, for readability

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_FILENAME_LEN 50

void getName( int x, int y )
{
    int  arr2[x][y];
    char userIn[ MAX_FILENAME_LEN ];
    FILE* graFile;

    printf("%s", "Enter filename: ");
    if( scanf("%49s", userIn) != 1)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed to read file name\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    graFile = fopen(userIn, "r");

    if( !graFile )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        if( fscanf( graFile, 
                    "%d%d%d%d%d", 
                    &arr2[i][0], 
                    &arr2[i][1], 
                    &arr2[i][2],
                    &arr2[i][3],
                    &arr2[i][4] ) != 5 )
        {
            fclose( graFile );
            fprintf( stderr, "fscanf failed to read row %d from the input file\n", i );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    fclose(graFile);

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", arr2[i][j]);
        }

        puts( "" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me out a lot. If I wanted to keep repeating the program until the user entered the correct file name, how could I do that? I know I would need a while loop but I'm not sure where to put it.

Comment: Nit *"uses `puts()` when appropriate"*, presuming you mean `puts( "" );` Why are you using a *string* function to output a single *char*? Perhaps `putchar ('\n');` for a single character? Also, better to explain that OP got wrong (though your answer clearly helped).

Comment: @Angie - short example, [Read from filename given as argument, or prompt until valid filename given](http://paste.opensuse.org/80832390)